# Python Mouse over image not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to detect when a Sprite has been hovered over by the mouse. However it is not working, it is never detecting the mouse over.

Code for Tile:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, img_sprite, init_position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.position=init_position
        self.image=pygame.image.load(img_sprite)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Code for event

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    for tile in tiles:
        if tile.image.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            print 'tile hovered'
```

Comment: *not working* is not descriptive enough. What is happening when you try it, and what did you expect? Is it never detecting, always detecting, or having issues with edge cases?

Comment: Never detecting the mouse over event.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if your mouse is over the rect that is the image rect. Since the rect returned by `image.get_rect()` is always in the form `(0,0,width,height)`, then your check only works if the position of your tile is at (0,0).

To fix this your can keep the position in the rect, or create a new rect that will describe the actual position.

You can also filter the events, and only check for a `MOUSEMOTION` event type.